# How to change angular 4 property on click event?

Tags: angular, properties, observable

I'm developing an angular app that uses an SVG library. In my component, I initiate the canvas load on ngAfterViewInit using a function. When I click on an object and the event fires I'm trying to set a property from inside the function call.

I've created a simple [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LOLb5pwhOezGZeXxln0r?p=preview) where I simply want the property 'title' to change to the new value. Console log of the 'this.title' value I try to set has the new value, but the view does not change. How do I trigger the view change?

I think this needs an observable, but as I am learning, I'm having a bit a trouble with the concept. Thanks in advance

```
import {Component, NgModule, ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

declare var Snap: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<p>{{title}}</p><svg id="svg"></svg>

`,
})
export class App implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  title: string = "Old Title";



  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.initcanvas();
  } 

  initcanvas(){
    var title;
    var canvas = Snap("#svg");
    canvas.circle(25,25,20,20).attr({fill: "black"});
    canvas.click(function(e){ console.log('clicked');
                  title = "New Title";
                  this.title= title; 
                  console.log(this.title);
                  console.log(title);
                  canvas.circle(25,25,20,20).attr({fill: "red"}); })
    canvas.append();
  }
}
```

Comment: `this` is scoped to the functions scope when used inside of a javascript `function()`, try using arrow syntax `(e) => {this.title = title; ...}` `this` now refers to the component's scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LLai mentioned, the problem is that your are building a function inside your `.click()` method which has a contained scope. Swap it from a `function()` declaration to arrow syntax to set the scope of the function to the entire component:

```
canvas.click((e) => { console.log('clicked');
              title = "New Title";
              this.title= title; 
              console.log(this.title);
              console.log(title);
              canvas.circle(25,25,20,20).attr({fill: "red"}); }
```

Here is a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/M1Oz3yf1cxRZXq5zJYB7?p=preview) forked from yours.

Comment: Updated with fix on console log typo.

Comment: Thank you z-bagley and llai for your help.. I've read this in few manuals and still bites me.. I will convert all my functions.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read the documentation more carefully.

```
http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.node 
https://plnkr.co/edit/hYKtZPzvSQehj3DKO5Et?p=preview
```

Comment: thanks for your input. My question did not have to do with Snap.. I got that part covered.